# In how many ways can a class of eight students be divided into four groups each having two students?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose there are eight students in a class. We have to divide them into four groups each having two students. The question is, in how many ways can it be done?

The answer is: $$\frac{8C2 \cdot 6C2 \cdot 4C2 \cdot 2C2}{4!}$$

I have a small confusion. Why do we need to divide by 4!?

Comment: We would need to divide by the $4!$ at the end to account for the fact that we can't tell the groups apart.  (12)(34)(56)(78) is the same "grouping" to me as (34)(12)(65)(87).  Not only is order within each group irrelevant, but also the order in which the groups themselves are presented irrelevant.  If we had a group1, a group2, etc... where we can actually distinguish between different groups, we would not need to divide by the $4!$.

Answer (score 4):

A method to count this without needing to rely on dividing for symmetry:

Take your eight students and arrange them in some standard fashion.  For the purpose of illustration, I will choose to do this by height, but other methods of ordering will work as well.

- Take the shortest person in the group.  (*there is no choice to be made here, it is predetermined*).
- Pick a person not yet taken to be made the shortest person's group partner.  (*Seven choices available*)
- From those six people remaining, take the shortest remaining person in the group.  (*again, there is no choice to be made here, it is predetermined based on previous choices*)
- Pick a person still remaining to be made this person's group partner.  (*Five choices available*)
- $\vdots$  Repeat the process, taking the current shortest person from those remaining and then picking a partner for them.

Applying multiplication principle, there are $1\cdot 7\cdot 1\cdot 5\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 7\cdot 5\cdot 3 = 7!! = 105$ (*here $7!!$ is [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) notation*)

Note that this is equal to $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\frac{1}{4!}=\binom{8}{2,2,2,2}\frac{1}{4!}=\frac{8!}{(2!)^44!} = 105$

---

Explaining the way the answer was written and how to view it that way,

Temporarily assign group names: group1, group2, group3, group4.

Arrange the eight people into these groups with 2 each in $\binom{8}{2,2,2,2}$ ways.  (*to see this, pick two to go to group1, then pick two remaining to go to group 2, etc... for a total of $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ ways*)

Now, recognize that we have counted every scenario exactly $4!$ times each since each rearrangement of the group names yields the "same" outcome.  Dividing by $4!$ corrects our count, making the total:

$\binom{8}{2,2,2,2}\frac{1}{4!}=105$